# How can I make newly created directories inside a directory with the setgid bit also have the setgid bit?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, command-line-interface, setgid

I give a directory the setgid bit.  Then inside that directory I create another directory, and I want it to also have the setgid bit.  I have tried something like umask 6002, but it says "octal number out of range."  Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, it does that. The newly created folders in a directory which has SGID will have the same permission and group ownership:

```
# ls -ld folder/
drwxr-sr-x 10 quanta quanta 4096 Oct 27 21:32 folder/
# mkdir folder/test
# ls -ld folder/test/
drwxr-sr-x 2 root quanta 4096 Oct 27 21:33 folder/test/
```

Comment: Ah, I see what happened.  This does work when manually creating files, but when using mv to bring in files, the setgid bit is ignored.  Is there a way around this?

Comment: @dvcolgan: "create" is "mkdir". "mv" is "move into". What are you actually trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

a) Use `cp -R` instead of `mv`

b) Use `find ./path/ -type d -exec chmod g+rwxs {} \;` after `mv`